# How to recover ImageField value in Django when it returns an Error?

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a form which contains an imagefield and some other fields.

my view looks like this:

```
def post_view(request):
    def errorHandle(errors,form):
        return render_to_response('post_form.html', {
                'errors':errors,
                'form' : form,
        },context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
        form = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES) # A form bound to the POST data
        if form.is_valid(): # All validation rules pass
            #save
        else:
            errors = form.errors
            return errorHandle(errors,form)
    else:
        form = PostForm() # An unbound form
        sucess = ''
        return render_to_response('post_form.html', {
            'form': form,
        }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

When errorHandle is called, it returns to the page with the form, errors and the values entered except for the value entered on an ImageField.

tell me if you need to look at my form and model. thanks in advance.

Comment: Excuse me. What do you mean for 'recover imagefield value'? Recover path to your image?

Comment: @sergzach yes. i want to recover the path that was given by the user.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's normal.

Path of a client image is secure for a backend, so, it was not sent. It's an official HTTP feature.